# Backbone.js views with nested tabs

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-routing

I write an application which consists from nested tabs. As an example I took https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone-boilerplate. I also use RequireJS.

I have at least two levels of nested tabs. Some of them have similar structure and I can reuse their views.

For example, I have the tab named "Articles" which contains the tabs: "New", "Changed", "Deleted" (in practise the number of tabs is much more). I have about the following routes:

```
/articles
/articles/new
/articles/changed/
/articles/deleted
```

These routes maps to the method named "showPanel" which takes two arguments: panel and subPanel. Using these arguments I want to show needed panel.

Is there any pattern which I can apply to resolve this issue or any other examples? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

look at [this](http://jsbin.com/iribul/14/edit), hope to be able to help you :)

showPanel method is a general method, show panel and subPanel:

```
function showPanel(panel, subPanel){
  $('#panels').children().hide().filter(panel).show().children().hide().filter(subPanel).show();
}
```

routes config:

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    'articles': 'articlesPanel',
    'articles/:subPanel': 'articlesSubPanel'
  },
  articlesPanel: function(){
    showPanel('#articles', '');
  },
  articlesSubPanel: function(subPanel){
    showPanel('#articles', '#'+subPanel);
  }

});
```

Comment: please provide an answer, not only a link

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Looks interesting but I think it is not that actually I look for. I need create views not just show/hide existing.